# Personal practices of meditation

Tags: personal-practice, vipassana

During practice of meditation when notice thoughts disappear . experience peace and happy . innerconversation has lost. what is this state?

Answer (score 3):

The state described is basic *samadhi* ('concentration'; 'collectedness'), which ideally is to be maintained & developed when meditating. MN 19 describes about how the Buddha-To-Be developed samadhi, in the following manner:

> I steadied my mind internally, **quieted** it, brought it to singleness, and concentrated it...So that my mind was **not strained**. Tireless energy was aroused in me and unremitting mindfulness was established, my body was **tranquil** and **untroubled**, my mind concentrated and unified. Quite secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unwholesome states, I entered upon and abided in the first jhāna, which is accompanied by applied and sustained mind, with rapture and pleasure born of seclusion.
>
> [MN 19](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn19)

Comment: today during meditation lost the hearing of sounds and feel go into something.is it still Samadhi?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to practice Samadhi?

How I practice, Samadhi plays only a supportive role. When I started practicing  Mahasi dry Satipatthana I was practicing Samadhi by accident(I hear that this is a common thing with beginners of this kind of practice). I was not focusing on the actual moment by moment sensation of the breath. I was focusing on my own moment by moment "guess" of what the breath actually was.  I would picture the breath in my mind or I would focus on the noting word "rising, falling" or "in, out" in some way but none of these things were an actual reality happening moment by moment. I was feeling great peace but I wasn't practicing the way I intended to practice.

At some point I started **just watching the sensation of the breath as it happened** and I stopped experiencing so much peace during this practice but this is the way to "see things as they are" and gain wisdom but I still got to practice Metta.

When I practice Metta, I feel great peace and joy. The mindfulness gained from seeing things as they are allows me to know when to have metta or  compassion for myself.

This is just what I have experienced. I hope it helps.